# C++ custom range type MSVC compiles but G++ doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, g++

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to learn C++ because it's a great IDE that catches errors on the spot. My program below shows no error and compiles just fine using MSVC, but when I tried compiling with G++ 10.1 it won't do it

```
#include <cstdio>

class FiboIterator {
    int current{ 1 };
    int last{ 1 };
public:
    bool operator!=(int x) const {
        return x >= current;
    }
    FiboIterator& operator++() {
        const auto tmp = current;
        current += last;
        last = tmp;
        return *this;
    }
    int operator*() {
        return current;
    }
};

class FiboRange {
    const int max;
public:
    explicit FiboRange(int max): max{max} {}
    FiboIterator begin() const {
        return FiboIterator{};
    }
    int end() const {
        return max;
    }
};

int main() {
    for (const auto i : FiboRange{ 5000 }) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}
```

The g++ outputs the following message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:34:38: error: inconsistent begin/end types in range-based 'for' statement: 'FiboIterator' and 'int'
   34 |  for (const auto i : FiboRange{ 5000 }) {
      |                                      ^
main.cpp:34:38: error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'FiboIterator' requested
main.cpp:34:38: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'FiboIterator' and 'FiboIterator')
main.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: 'bool FiboIterator::operator!=(int) const'
    7 |  bool operator!=(int x) const {
      |       ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:7:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'FiboIterator' to 'int'
    7 |  bool operator!=(int x) const {
      |                  ~~~~^
```

Is there a significant difference between MSVC and G++? If I would like to make custom range works with G++, how should I change my code? Thanks.

Comment: Did you provide -std=c++17 key to the gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @vlad-from-moscow, this is probably a MSVC bug, because default settings of Visual Studio 2019 is C++14. It shouldn't compile.

Your code is correct since c++17.
If you use c++17 your code would compile on GCC and CLang.

The realization of range-based for loop has changed.

C++11:

```
{
   auto && __range = range_expression ; 
   for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
       __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
       range_declaration = *__begin; 
       loop_statement 
   }
}
```

C++17:

```
{        
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

Your begin iterator has type FiboIterator, your end iterator is of type int.

```
// c++11 version fails, auto can't deduce type
auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; // an error here

// C++17 version works fine, they are different types.
auto __begin = begin_expr ;
auto __end = end_expr;
```

If you do not want to use C++17, then you should make return types of begin and end the same and the comparison operator for FiboIterator as well.

```
#include <cstdio>

class FiboIterator {
    int current{ 1 };
    int last{ 1 };
public:
    FiboIterator(int x=1) : current{x} {}

    bool operator!=(FiboIterator x) const {
        return x.current >= current;
    }
    FiboIterator& operator++() {
        const auto tmp = current;
        current += last;
        last = tmp;
        return *this;
    }
    int operator*() {
        return current;
    }
};

class FiboRange {
    const int max;
public:
    explicit FiboRange(int max): max{max} {}

    FiboIterator begin() const {
        return FiboIterator{};
    }
    FiboIterator end() const {
        return FiboIterator{max};
    }
};
```

Comment: The C++ standard maybe the issue like you have pointed out. I made sure that MSVC was using C++17, while I'm not sure which standard my g++ 10.1 is using, so how do I find out? How do I set it to C++17? I tried out your solution it works well. However, the original code was in order to show that range-based for loops work even if **begin()** and **end()** return types are different, so I guess C++17 is the only way to go here

Comment: You can provide it with -std=c++17 flag. By default it is 14 or 11.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a bug of MS VS.

The range-based for loop in particular is converted to the statement like

```
for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
__end = end-expr;
__begin != __end;
++__begin )
```

That is there is used the declaration

```
auto __begin = begin-expr, __end = end-expr;
```

However your functions begin and end have different return types.

```
FiboIterator begin() const {
    return FiboIterator{};
}
int end() const {
    return max;
}
```

So you may not use the placeholder specifier `auto` in such a declaration.

Comment: Actually the point of this program is to show how a range-based for loop can still works even if **begin()** and **end()** return types are different (hence the **operator!=()**). The code comes from a C++ book so I don't think it's a bug, it should work! Perhaps g++ is not using C++17 standard? Like indicated, i'm using g++ 10.1